# AFAmazonS3Manager Error

Tags: objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, xcode6

I'm trying to use the `AFAmazonS3Manager` in my app. I'm attempting to upload a photo to Amazon but I keep getting this error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this server." UserInfo=0x1740e3f00 {NSUnderlyingError=0x170247dd0 "The requested URL was not found on this server.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/myInfo, NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/myInfo, NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

My code for the thing is simply:

```
    AFAmazonS3Manager * s3Manager = [[AFAmazonS3Manager alloc]initWithAccessKeyID:amazonAccessKey secret:amazonSecret];
s3Manager.requestSerializer.region = AFAmazonS3USStandardRegion;
s3Manager.requestSerializer.bucket = amazonBucket;

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:photoName];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(photo) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

[s3Manager postObjectWithFile:filePath destinationPath:@"" parameters:nil progress:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

    int percent = roundf((float)totalBytesWritten / (float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite * 100);
    NSLog(@"Percent Complete: %d%%",percent);
```

I've been at this problem for a couple of days. I'm new to using AWS, so I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you're passing an invalid request URL or it's an image that doesn't exist in the path you're giving, base on the error message.Please check the url path you're using if an image really exist there or if it's valid by copy pasting the url in your browser. here's a link that might also help you : http://www.splinter.com.au/2014/10/15/upload-to-s3-from-ios/